# How to create birt runtime object as singleton in spring

Tags: java, spring, birt, singleton-type

I want to create a singleton birt object, as birt object is heavy weight object, I am new to this technoogy so any help would be appericiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [singleton scope](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-singleton) for this object in app context:

```
<bean id="accountController" class="com.foo.DefaultAccountController" />

<!-- (singleton scope is the default) -->
<bean id="accountService" class="com.foo.DefaultAccountService" />
```

Then you can autowire dependency in some declared bean like this:

```
public class DefaultAccountController {
    @Autowired
    private DefaultAccountService accService;

    ...
}
```

Detailed information can be found in [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html).

Comment: how to pass that object to other class.